# Selectorlib shows image link in chrome preview but scrapy crawler doesn´t (alibaba)

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors, web-crawler

I almost completed a webscraper for alibaba.com by using Python, Selectorlib and Scrapy crawler. Everything is extracted as the preview of the Selectorlib chrome extension shows except product images. In the preview it shows the following:

Preview:

```
"//s.alicdn.com/@sc04/kf/Ha9da3f369297426186899d591eaaf568u.jpg_300x300.jpg",
"//s.alicdn.com/@sc04/kf/Hd807c89377a3421eb62a28be8e12a3b2c.jpg_300x300.jpg",
"//s.alicdn.com/@sc04/kf/H39a5f2fdd4e44daca1fa86c6da5e41caV.jpg_300x300.jpg",
```

and so on...

But when i run the scraper through windows powershell it only returns 2 of the 21 image links. All the other 'product images' return as "Image: None". It seems that there is a difference between the preview in chrome (f12 menu) and the crawler. I downloaded the yaml file a couple of times after saving to make sure it is the correct file. If you need more info on the code or smth please let me know. I am fairly new to this so i could be missing something. Changing it from attribute: src to image or even link doesn't help.

The page(s) url i am scraping is:

```
https://www.alibaba.com/trade/search?fsb=y&IndexArea=product_en&CatId=&SearchText=airco
```

"products:

```
css: 'div[data-content="productItem"]'
xpath: null
multiple: true
type: Text
children:
    name:
        css: p.elements-title-normal__content
        xpath: null
        multiple: true
        type: Text
    price:
        css: span.elements-offer-price-normal__price
        xpath: null
        multiple: true
        type: Text
    seller_name:
        css: a.fc3
        xpath: null
        multiple: true
        type: Text
    seller_years:
        css: span.seller-tag__year
        xpath: null
        type: Text
    seller_rating:
        css: span.seb-supplier-review-gallery-test__score
        xpath: null
        multiple: true
        type: Text
    seller_reviews:
        css: span.seb-supplier-review__review-count
        xpath: null
        multiple: true
        type: Text
    Link:
        css: a.elements-title-normal
        xpath: null
        multiple: true
        type: Link
    Image:
        css: img.J-img-switcher-item
        xpath: null
        type: Attribute
        attribute: src"
```

I'll humbly wait and hope someone can help me with the issue.

Thanks in advance!!

Ps. now it only extracts one in eight image links like this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu2q9.png)

Comment: The difference is javascript. Most modern webpages include javascript, which is code that runs in the browser and modifies the DOM, or webpage you currently have open. Your scraper most likely cannot execute javascript, and gets a very different webpage to your browser. You can test this: use your scraper to load the webpage you want, and dump it to file. Then open the same page in your browser, and save it to another file, and compare the two. You'll likely notice huge differences.

Comment: Hi Danielle, thanks for your fast reply i appreciate it a lot. I tested the difference as you stated above. It did change a bit so i adjusted the selector and the same happens again. (The images were still highlighted when i selected them in selectorlib and it recognized the same selections on both pages). Again the preview shows the links but my scraper can't seem to get them. But any other Item for example "Link" works just fine.

Comment: By the way the images on the website are in a slider from image 1/6. I don't know if this makes a difference or not but thought better to mention it.